# VBA Excel and Access - Add attachment to certain record in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, attachment

I have an Excel file that reads and writes data to Access. I want to be able to add attachments to certain records. So far, I have managed to write code that adds an attachment to a new record in the desired table. However, I can't manage to add the attachment to a certain record. Here is the code in Excel VBA:

```
Public adodbConnectionString As String
Public adodbConnection As ADODB.Connection
Public adodbRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Public daoDB As DAO.database
Public daoWS As DAO.Workspace
Public daoRecordset As DAO.Recordset
Public daoRecordset2 As DAO.Recordset
Public daoFields2 As DAO.Field2

Public Function refreshPath() 'this function updates the path to the .accdb-file globally

pathDb = "[...]\Data.accdb"

End Function
Sub exportAttachmentToAccess() ' this function adds the attachment to the table

refreshPath

Dim filePath As String

filePath = SelectFile()

If Len(filePath) = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert "No file selected!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set daoWS = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set daoDB = OpenDatabase(pathDb)
Set daoRecordset = daoDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM N_C_A;", dbOpenDynaset)

daoRecordset.AddNew
    Set daoRecordset2 = daoRecordset.Fields("Test1").value 'Test1 is the field name where the attachments are stored
    
    daoRecordset2.AddNew
        daoRecordset2.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile filePath
    daoRecordset2.Update

daoRecordset.Update

daoRecordset.Close
Set daoRecordset = Nothing
Set daoDB = Nothing

End Sub
```

[This is the Access table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpbsN.png)

As you can see, the attachments end up on a new record every time i run the macro. However, when I change
daoRecordset.AddNew
to
daoRecordset.Edit
it adds the attachment to the first record.

How do I add the attachment to **ID 12**, i.e. the fourth record?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM N_C_A where id = 12"` will only query the record you want to update.  Likewise, when adding new records you can use `"SELECT * FROM N_C_A where false"` since you only need an empty recordset to add a new record to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving objects in table consumes Access 2GB size limit. Often better to leave attachments external and save path in text field.

Options:

1. apply filter in SQL to open daoRecordset only with record that should be updated

```
daoDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM N_C_A WHERE ID =" & Me!ID, dbOpenDynaset)
```

2. use recordset FindFirst method to go to desired record

```
daoRecordset.FindFirst "ID = " & Me!ID
If Not daoRecordset.NoMatch Then
    'code to add attachment
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. After considering the size of the attachments, I realize that those 2 gb will be used fairly quickly. I will store them externally and keep the path to the image in access.